# Configurar paginas de error desde web.config o IIS con un subdominio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, iis

No puedo mostrar mi pagina de error cuando en la `url` tengo un subdominio y esta pagina no existe.

En la configuración de mi `web.config` tengo lo siguiente:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPag/Error500" mode="On">
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/ErrorPag/Error403" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPag/Error404" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ErrorPag/Error500" />
    <error statusCode="503" redirect="~/ErrorPag/Error503" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

funciona correctamente cuando accedo a mi dominio de esta forma: `localhost/ErrorPag/Error` *(esta pagina no existe)*, pero si yo entro de esta otra manera que es con subdominio no me funciona: `subdom.localhost/ErrorPag/Error` me muestra el siguiente error *(la típica pagina amarilla del `IIS`)*:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
>
> Error en runtime
>
> Descripción: Se produjo una excepción al procesar la solicitud.
>   Asimismo, se produjo otra excepción al ejecutar la página de error
>   personalizada para la primera excepción. Se ha terminado la solicitud.

Por otro lado si yo accedo de manera correcta a la pagina de error con subdominio me la muestra, es decir que la url que ingreso en el navegador de esta forma : `subdom.localhost/ErrorPag/Error404` se muestra correctamente

**¿Qué configuración debo tener en el `web.config` o en el `IIS` para que funcione de la manera correcta?**

Por ahora utilizo esta configuración en el `web.config`, pero necesito mantener el subdominio, ya que por medio del subdominio obtengo información referente al usuario que inicio la sesión.

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors defaultRedirect="http://localhost/ErrorPag/Error500" mode="On">
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="http://localhost/ErrorPag/Error403" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="http://localhost/ErrorPag/Error404" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="http://localhost/ErrorPag/Error500" />
    <error statusCode="503" redirect="http://localhost/ErrorPag/Error503" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

> **Nota 1:** Considerando que no solo es un subdominio, para ser más especifico es un **dominio comodín***(*.miDominio.com.mx)*
>
> **Nota2:** La configuración que uso para capturar el subdominio se encuentra en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/44932/6635) en `SubdomainRoute`.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar a añadir en la configuracion del IIS una pagina de error a tu sitio desde el propio IIS.

Para ello tendrías que `Abrir IIS->Selecciona el sitio-->Haz doble clic en Páginas de errores de .Net-->click derecho y agregar.`

En al ventana que se te abre tendrás que agregar un código de error, en tu caso 404 y la dirección URL Absoluta de tu página de error.

Si esto no te funciona, podrías probar a añadir la página de error personalizada para el propio dominio del IIS() el contenedor de tus sitios.

O como otra opción, podrías hacerlo desde la propia configuración del DNS, añadiendo un registro para redirigir todos los subdominios (*) al dominio completo

Comment: La primera parte se hace automáticamente, ya que las tengo configuradas desde el `web.config`, por otro lado no puedo redirigir los subdominios al dominio completo debido a que el dominio principal es un sitio completamente diferente a uno con subdominio

Comment: Pero aunque sea diferente no habría problema en redirigirlo. haz unan prueba. Haz un ping a tu localhost y otro a CualquierDominio.localhost. SI no está configurado los DNS el ping a localhost te resolverá correctamente pero al subdominio no sabrá a donde dirigirse. Por eos digo que tienes que configurar previamente el DNS para que sepa resolver esa direccion

Comment: @JuankGlezz Pudiste probar ha realizar el ping al subdominio?

Comment: Investigue como hacerlo, pero no obtuve resultado alguno, a parte de eso yo no tengo mucho conocimiento sobre configurar el IIS, crees poder proporcionarme alguna guía o los pasos para hacerlo?